# unable to deploy shiny app in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to deploy an app i made in Rshiny since couple of day unsuccessfully......Locally its working beautifully...only problem comes when i try to publish to Shinyapps.io account.....

I loaded the packages globally (in apps.r script) as:

## Loading the required packages

```
mLoad <- function(...) {
  sapply(sapply(match.call(), as.character)[-1], require, character.only = TRUE)
}

mLoad(cluster,plyr,dplyr,DT,data.table,ggfortify,ggcorrplot,ggraph,ggplot2,ggthemes,imputeTS,knitr,markdown,purrr,randomForest,rCharts,reshape2,rpivotTable,rsconnect,shiny,shinythemes,shinyapps,tibble,tidyr,tidyverse,vegan,VIM,visdat)
```

I am getting the following error while deploying.....

```
An error has occurred

The application failed to start.

Loading required package: cluster
Loading required package: plyr
Loading required package: dplyr

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:plyr’:

    arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise,
    summarize

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Loading required package: DT

Attaching package: ‘DT’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    dataTableOutput, renderDataTable

Loading required package: data.table
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘data.table’
Loading required package: ggfortify
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘ggfortify’
Loading required package: ggcorrplot
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: ggraph
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘ggraph’
Loading required package: ggthemes
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘ggthemes’
Loading required package: imputeTS
Loading required package: knitr
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘knitr’
Loading required package: markdown
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘markdown’
Loading required package: purrr
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘purrr’
Loading required package: randomForest
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘randomForest’
Loading required package: rCharts
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘rCharts’
Loading required package: reshape2
Loading required package: rpivotTable
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘rpivotTable’
Loading required package: rsconnect
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘rsconnect’
Loading required package: shinythemes
Loading required package: shinyapps
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘shinyapps’
Loading required package: tibble
Loading required package: tidyr
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘tidyr’
Loading required package: tidyverse
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
Loading required package: vegan
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘vegan’
Loading required package: VIM
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘VIM’
Loading required package: visdat
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘visdat’
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : could not find function "rpivotTableOutput"
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted..
```

As far as i know all the required packages have been installed locally either from CRAN or Github.....Still dont know why i am getting the above error....

There seems to be a conflict somewhere between some packages....cant figure out where....

Answer (score 2):

Solved the Shiny deployment issue......just had to place the library name in ui part of `rpivotTableOutput("mypivot")` as shown below...

`rpivotTable::rpivotTableOutput("mypivot")`..

Infact even after deployment many functions were not working (locally the app worked seamlessly)....for ex...rename() of dplyr even after loading the dplyr library.....one just had to put the library name in front of the function....`dplyr::rename()`.....had to do for many functions in the app...in `server` as well as `ui` portions of the shiny code....

Plz see my shiny app here:

```
https://nishantsbi.shinyapps.io/microsegmentation_ml_app/
```